# OkHttp not working as it should

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am fairly new to Android Dev and I created a Google Form and wanted to implement the form on my app and I heard about the open source **okhttp** from Square Open Source, which you most likely know

So, I created a layout with the labels, gave them the same IDs and everything...
I created a java class called **Form** and inserted all the code, and no errors whatsoever.

(Worth mentioning I am using navigation drawer activity, don't know if that influences or not though)

So after implementing and correcting everything there was to correct, I ran the application but it just doesnt do anything. It does not do the validation nor it sends the response.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out with this

I will leave the code here

Once again, thanks.

```
package com.example.eduardobastos.testapp;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;


public class Form extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final MediaType FORM_DATA_TYPE
        = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
//URL derived from form URL
public static final String URL="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeZp9wjprZJ3OR2SkIHHsZE9yDBAVnC7mO8hPKSzwGuYhqmdw/formResponse";
//input element ids found from the live form page
public static final String EMAIL_KEY="entry_943499687";
public static final String SUBJECT_KEY="entry_2058392291";
public static final String MESSAGE_KEY="entry_1420026128";

private Context context;
private EditText emailEditText;
private EditText subjectEditText;
private EditText messageEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.form_layout);

    //save the activity in a context variable to be used afterwards
    context =this;

    //Get references to UI elements in the layout
    Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    emailEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
    subjectEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.subjectEditText);
    messageEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Make sure all the fields are filled with values
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(emailEditText.getText().toString()) ||
                    TextUtils.isEmpty(subjectEditText.getText().toString()) ||
                    TextUtils.isEmpty(messageEditText.getText().toString()))
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"All fields are mandatory.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            //Check if a valid email is entered
            if(!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailEditText.getText().toString()).matches())
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Please enter a valid email.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            //Create an object for PostDataTask AsyncTask
            PostDataTask postDataTask = new PostDataTask();

            //execute asynctask
            postDataTask.execute(URL,emailEditText.getText().toString(),
                    subjectEditText.getText().toString(),
                    messageEditText.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}



//AsyncTask to send data as a http POST request
private class PostDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... contactData) {
        Boolean result = true;
        String url = contactData[0];
        String email = contactData[1];
        String subject = contactData[2];
        String message = contactData[3];
        String postBody="";

        try {
            //all values must be URL encoded to make sure that special characters like & | ",etc.
            //do not cause problems
            postBody = EMAIL_KEY+"=" + URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8") +
                    "&" + SUBJECT_KEY + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(subject,"UTF-8") +
                    "&" + MESSAGE_KEY + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(message,"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            result=false;
        }



        try{
            //Create OkHttpClient for sending request
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            //Create the request body with the help of Media Type
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(FORM_DATA_TYPE, postBody);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            //Send the request
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        }catch (IOException exception){
            result=false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
        //Print Success or failure message accordingly
        Toast.makeText(context,result?"Message successfully sent!":"There was some error in sending message. Please try again after some time.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried debugging ? does it enter the doInBackground method of the task ?

Comment: Hi Jav T. I will try that in 4/5h. I just went to bed. It's 6:30am here. Did you notice anything else that I should check or that is wrong/not good?

Comment: Not at all, keep me posted about the debug operations, also i  can give you a few tips about using that task class ;)

Comment: I would love that. Any way we can communicate ?

Comment: Hey ! Any updates on the debugging?

Comment: Sorry was at the hospital... Nothing really :/   And my time is is kind of running out for the submission...

Comment: Hey, i just posted a test i just did and worked, please try and adjust it to your code and let me know if you have any problem, maybe an issue with the EditText objects or something, try and hardcode it like i did and test it

Comment: Also check your internet permissions on manifest... be sure to have : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: If you arr still in trouble send me your skype username and ill be gald to help you out...

Comment: Thanks Jav. I am going to try it soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this, and works like a charm...

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import mx.com.iisi.staffing.R;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new PostDataTask(this).execute("","testing@testing.com","Testing","Testing message");
    }

    private class PostDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        public final MediaType FORM_DATA_TYPE
                = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
        //URL derived from form URL
        public static final String URL="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeZp9wjprZJ3OR2SkIHHsZE9yDBAVnC7mO8hPKSzwGuYhqmdw/formResponse";
        //input element ids found from the live form page
        public static final String EMAIL_KEY="entry_943499687";
        public static final String SUBJECT_KEY="entry_2058392291";
        public static final String MESSAGE_KEY="entry_1420026128";
        private Context context;

        public PostDataTask(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... contactData) {
            Boolean result = true;
            String url = contactData[0];
            String email = contactData[1];
            String subject = contactData[2];
            String message = contactData[3];
            String postBody="";

            try {
                //all values must be URL encoded to make sure that special characters like & | ",etc.
                //do not cause problems
                postBody = EMAIL_KEY+"=" + URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8") +
                        "&" + SUBJECT_KEY + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(subject,"UTF-8") +
                        "&" + MESSAGE_KEY + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(message,"UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                result=false;
            }



            try{
                //Create OkHttpClient for sending request
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                //Create the request body with the help of Media Type
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(FORM_DATA_TYPE, postBody);
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(URL)
                        .post(body)
                        .build();
                //Send the request
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            }catch (IOException exception){
                result=false;
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
            Toast.makeText(context,result?"Message successfully sent!":"There was some error in sending message. Please try again after some time.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ill add you in an hour ok?

Comment: Sure... My time is GMT, so here is 3am. I am awake I willl accept you